How to manage versioning on MS project with vba?
As a PMO I need to update plannings, therefore I need to update the new version number that figures on the left legend of MS Project (for printing). In the image we see where I put the new version. The place where I manage the version
Every time I change the planning I need to change the version number. I want to create a macro to automate the change. I achieved to modify the text :
FilePageSetupLegendEx Alignment:=pjLeft, Text:="Project: " & projectName & " SCHEDULE  Iss 13.0" & Chr(13) & "Date: " & todayDay

But I didn't find any solution to read the text (i.e. the left legend that contains the version number) nor to stock it. I tried to use file properties, but there are read-only. Do you know any solution on VBA to stock data without changing the planning ? Or how to retrieve the legend information ? Do you have any solution on a different language, e.g. Python ?

Please do not post code as a picture. Include the code as text.

The Title can be read with the following:
ActiveProject.BuiltInDocumentProperties(1)
The same line of code can be used to set the new Title

Thank you for the reply. The problem is that the information I'm seeking is on the legend printing project, as showed on the image.
If I don't find any other solution, I will try to keep the versionning on the title as well

Fran Lannou - What you see in the legend IS the Title. You can add other info, but the file identification text is the Title.
